# I can not solve this equation for recurrence

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

Use RSolver to solve

```
RSolve [{f [n + 1] == f [n] + 2 n + 1, f [1] == -3}, f [n], n]
```

but I do not get solution

Edit

my solution

[image]

Comment: It works for me, giving `{{f[n] -> -4 + n^2}}`.  What do you get in return?

Comment: Works on "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

Comment: Make sure both `f`` and `n` are undefined (can use `Clear` for this).

Comment: Works on "9.0 for Linux x86 (32-bit) (November 20, 2012)"

Comment: 99 times out of 100, the error you describe is because you accidentally used `=` instead of `==` when you first typed in the code.  This sets the value in memory;  so Mathematica now thinks that `f[1]` is equal to 3;  and when you correct the code, that value is still stored in memory, so the corrected equation evaluates to `True`.  The easiest way to fix the problem is to reboot the kernel (or to quit & restart the program, which does the same thing.)

Comment: thanks , a nice sign, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

**Code:**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
RSolve[{f[n + 1] == f[n] + 2 n + 1, f[1] == -3}, f[n], n]
```

**Output:**

```
{{f[n] -> -4 + n^2}}
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)